# IE11: Extend table row beyond table on hover

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position, internet-explorer-11

I have an HTML table inside a container. On hover, I want to highlight the row, not only inside the table, but extending outside to the edges of the container.

This is my first attempt:

```css
body {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 800px;
  border: 1px dotted gray;
  padding: 2rem;
}

table {
  table-layout: fixed;
  border-collapse: collapse;
  width: 100%;
  border: 1px dashed purple;
}

td, th {
  padding: .25rem;
  position: relative;
  text-align: left;
}

tr:hover {
  background: lightgray;
  cursor: pointer;
}

tr:hover td:first-child::before, tr:hover td:last-child::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 2rem;
  background-color: lightgray;
}

td:first-child::before {
  left: -2rem;
}

td:last-child::after {
  right: -2rem;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <th>Dato</th>
      <th>Lok. nr.</th>
      <th>Navn</th>
      <th>Status</th>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td>06.12.2016</td>
        <td>25736</td>
        <td>Josommar-<br>set</td>
        <td>I arbeid</td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>07.12.2016</td>
        <td>10232</td>
        <td>Mannbru-<br>holmen</td>
        <td>Avsluttet</td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

It works fine in Chrome, but I have to support IE11, and in IE the `before` and `after` elements do not have the correct height. You can see the result in the screenshot below.

[image: Internet Explorer 11]

How can I do this in a way that also works in IE11?